# C++ - Will deleting a vector of structs that contain vectors cause memory leaks?

Tags: c++, memory-management, memory-leaks, vector, struct

I am building a game and have a vector of objects called sprites.

```
struct Sprite
{
    SpriteType texture;     // The texture enumeration
    float x;                // The x position of the sprite
    float y;                // The y position of the sprite
    float xVel;             // The x velocity of the sprite
    float yVel;             // The y velocity of the sprite
    int imgBlockX;          // The x block in the image
    int imgBlockY;          // The y block in the image
    int numFrames;          // The number of frames in the sprite animation
    int curFrame;           // The current frame of animation
    int delay;              // The delay between frame switches
    int elapsed;            // The amount of time on this frame
    long lastTime;          // The last update time
    long curTime;           // The current update time
    bool loop;              // Does this animation loop?
    int lifespan;           // The max lifespan of the sprite
    int order;              // 0 for first 1 for last
    bool hasChildren;       // Is this a parent sprite?
    int maxSize;
    std::vector<SpriteChild> children;// The sprites that are linked to this one (die when this one dies)
};
```

As you can see at the bottom, it contains a vector itself of sprite children. If I delete an element from my sprite vector will it cause a memory leak with the spritechild vector or is that taken care of?

Thanks!

Comment: How are `SpriteType` and `SpriteChild` defined? Are they pointers that own memory?

Answer (score 1):

Your vector is allocated as a member of the Sprite struct (it's not allocated via `new`), so it will be cleaned up automatically when the `Sprite` is deleted.

You get memory leaks when you create an object via `new` and do not `delete` it.

Answer (score 0):

No matter how you allocate sprite vector, deleting an element from it will will deallocate vector `children` specific to that object. Believe `SpriteChild` is not a typedef for a pointer type but a struct name.

Answer (score 0):

It will be taken care of if you don't mess up with `SpriteChild`. If it allocates something in constructor, make sure you free it in destructor. IIRC `struct` is not much different from `class` just it has as default `public` visibility of its members.

Comment: One more difference between a `struct` and a `class` type: inheritance for `struct` types is public by default, i.e., these are equivalent: `struct A : Whatever`, `struct A : public Whatever`.

Answer (score 0):

It will ONLY cause a leak if the destructor for SpriteChild is not properly defined
(I.E. the destructor for SpriteChild needs to delete any dynamically allocated
memory).

Deleting twice could cause a crash.

However, just deleting an object successfully allocated with new shouldn't result in a memory leak.